# Spam filter in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

Recently the one sender who I receive from most has been blocked. The messages do not appear in Junk or Junk E-mail folders, but show up if I search All Mail Items as being in a Spam folder. I can open them from the search results, but I don't have a Spam folder.
One correspondent says Outlook doesn't have a Spam folder and that it must be caused by and add-in, but I see no add-ins that might cause this.

Comment: Open Outlook in safe mode should prevent the add-ons

Answer (score 0):

A server-side spam filter would not show up as an add-on, as it would be hosted on the server.

For example, Trend Micro offers a product called "ScanMail Suite" that is installed on the mail server and adds "Spam mail" folders to all the mailboxes. (It can be configured to integrate with the existing Junk Mail folder, but that requires additional work)

If it is Trend Micro and ScanMail that is being used on the server, you can add it to the "approved senders list" right-clicking on the email in the search results, then selecting "Custom Action->Add to approved senders list". It is in a slightly different spot pre-Outlook 2010.

Similar techniques can be used for other software.